Conditional probability, thinning of a Poisson process involving microbes
Microbes outside a culture float by according to a Poisson process with rate $2\lambda$ per minute. Each microbe that floats by joins the population of the culture with probability $p$, independently of the times of arrival and choice to join of all other microbes.
Given that 7 microbes float by in the first 3 minutes, what is the probability that $\geq 2$ join the culture?
My approach is to first find the probability of the joint event, that $\geq 2$ join the culture and 7 float by in the first 3 minutes. To find that, subtract the probability that 0 join the culture (and 7 pass by) as well as the probability that 1 joins the culture (and 6 pass by) from the probability that 7 float by. Divide all that by the probability that 7 float by.
$$
\frac{\frac{e ^ {-6\lambda}(6\lambda) ^ 7}{7!} - \frac{e ^ {-6\lambda p}(6\lambda p) ^ 0}{0!}\frac{e ^ {-6\lambda p}(6\lambda(1 - p)) ^ 7}{7!} - \frac{e ^ {-6\lambda p}(6\lambda p) ^ 1}{1!}\frac{e ^ {-6\lambda p}(6\lambda(1 - p)) ^ 6}{6!}}{\frac{e ^ {-6\lambda}(6\lambda) ^ 7}{7!}} = 1 + (6\lambda p) ^ 7 - \frac{7(6\lambda p) ^ 7}{6\lambda}.
$$
Is this right?

Not following.  What's the significance of the Poisson process if we are told how many microbes appear?  Makes no difference how likely/unlikely it was, but there were $7$ of them.  So now you just have a simple binomial problem.  Or have I misunderstood?
